# Proton-proton collisions cross section plot by Stirling

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, large-hadron-collider, scattering-cross-section

I am struggling to understand some details of the cross section plot by Stirling that is very often shown when talking about LHC physics. See e.g. here: [http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/~wstirlin/plots/crosssections2012_v5.pdf](http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/%7Ewstirlin/plots/crosssections2012_v5.pdf)

I understand very well the discontinuity when switching from $p\bar{p}$ to pp collisions, however, what I don't get is what is meant with $\sigma_{b}$ and $\sigma_{t}$. Is this only referring to pair production, like $gg \rightarrow g \rightarrow b\bar{b}$ ? Or are processes that are experimenatally often called single-top production, like $qq' \rightarrow W \rightarrow tb$ included as well?

Moreover, what I completely miss is the meaning of the two lines splitting for the $\sigma_{b}$ cross section. Is this due to uncertainties as pdfs or different calculation schemes?

I would appreciate any help or kick into the right direction.

Comment: all figures have a paragraph  describing what is displayed. you have not linked that

Comment: Apparently not. I took it from http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/~wstirlin/plots/plots.html and there is no detailed explanation what is shown. I searched as well for a publication where this appears but it does not seem to be the case especially since the author wants that one uses "private communication" for referencing his work.

Comment: physics is about accuracy, not about guessing what the variables shown display. I can guess that it is about inclusive crossections , thats all. If you go to the link you supplied, there is an archive reference link where the paper with the words exists.    https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0002   It turns out it is a theoretical/phenomenological  paper with fits  before even the LHC started.  If the author says private communication maybe you should send an email and ask for explanation of symbols.  My guess is that σ_b  and  σ_t are the inclusive crossections for the bottom and top.

Comment: I guess that the split in the b crossection must be related to CP violation by  neutral bottom quark decays

Comment: I know that physics is about accuracy and to be 100% sure one has to ask the author of the plot. I just thought maybe someone in this community came across the problem already earlier and knows. The paper you referenced does not even show the plot. It is from 2009 and describes how they created their PDF set one often usess. The plot I referenced is from 2012 (the Higgs boson has already been found at that time). I agree with you that the sigmas are the pair production cross section (whatever they defined to go in there).

Comment: Still, the split remains unexplained. I am sorry, but I don't understand your second part. If the cross section is about b quark production why is it influenced by CP violation in neutral b meson/hadron decays (I guess you meant that because there is no neutral bottom quark)?

Comment: It is a guess, because there are no graph definitions. They give theoretical crossections for different cp violation or some such . I mean   http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-cp-violation.pdf .and B and T is for the hadrons not for the quarks., again a guess.

Comment: the sigmas are inclusive crossections for B hadrons and T hadrons etc

Comment: But this would be highly inconsistent. Especially since there are no T hadrons because with a life time of ~ 5*10^(-25)s the top quarks decay before they can hadronize.

Comment: the B hadrons are unstable too, but on their mass shell they are real,samefor the Z and  W .

Answer (score 0):

This is the inclusive cross section for b-quark pair-production which is something experiments can not really measure very precisely due to limited acceptance. The main way a b-quark pair is produced at the LHC is two initial state gluons fuse to one intermediate one that then splits into a final state b-quark pair. This is due to the fact that the gluon contribution dominates amongst the proton's pdf at very low Bjorken x. However, at very low x, the pdfs have huge uncertainties, e.g. for the pdf set Stirling used in the calculation (it can be seen here: https://mstwpdf.hepforge.org/). If you e.g. consider the case of having a momentum transfer just right to produce two b-Quarks at rest (~9 GeV) - at the Tevatron that corresponded to a larger x value than it does at the LHC. Unfortunately for a given set of PDFs with associated uncertainties one can only use the DGLAP equations to go from one Q^2 to another but not to move from one x to another. Therefore, one would need to include more data at low x in order to constrain these uncertainties, but they only used data mainly collected at HERA and the Tevatron. However, the set is as well outdated and newer PDF sets including LHC data exist (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00428). This is the reason why the line starts to split at really high sqrt(s) - schematically x ~ M_x/sqrt(s). This is also the reason why you don't see it e.g. for top-quark pair-production because to produce them at rest a much higher x is needed, which in turn has lower uncertainties. In addition to the pdf-related uncertainties, there are as well large contribution coming from the Matrix element itself, however, I do not elaborate much more on that...

Comment: are you saying that the split inthe sigma_b is because of two different data sets entering in the fit?

Comment: No, the split represents the uncertainty on the extrapolation. The dashed line is the mean value...

Comment: this is the reason why figures without their text are useless.

Comment: I totally agree :)